# "The application did not respond." but no errors

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I'm really new so don't judge me or mistakes I make. I followed some tutorials and looked at the discord.js docs, but found nothing on how to fix this. I just get "the application did not respond."

I just made some commands and I get this everytime.

ping.js:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('ping')
    .setDescription('Krijg de bot ping en Websocket ping.'),
    // devOnly: Boolean,
    
    // options: Object[],
    // deleted: true,
  
    async execute(client, interaction) {
      //await interaction.deferReply();

      const reply = await interaction.fetchReply();

      const ping = reply.createdTimestamp - interaction.createdTimestamp;

      await interaction.reply(`Pong! Bot: ${ping}ms | Websocket: ${client.ws.ping}ms.`);
    },
  };
```

interactionCreate -> handleCommands.js

```
const { devs, testServer } = require('../../../config.json');
const getLocalCommands = require('../../utils/getLocalCommands');

module.exports = async (client, interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

  const localCommands = getLocalCommands();

  try {
    const commandObject = localCommands.find(
      (cmd) => cmd.name === interaction.commandName
    );

    if (!commandObject) return;

    if (commandObject.devOnly) {
      if (!devs.includes(interaction.member.id)) {
        interaction.reply({
          content: 'Alleen bestuur mag deze command uitvoeren.',
          ephemeral: true,
        });
        return;
      }
    }

    if (commandObject.testOnly) {
      if (!(interaction.guild.id === testServer)) {
        interaction.reply({
          content: 'Deze command is alleen in testmodus beschikbaar.',
          ephemeral: true,
        });
        return;
      }
    }

    if (commandObject.permissionsRequired?.length) {
      for (const permission of commandObject.permissionsRequired) {
        if (!interaction.member.permissions.has(permission)) {
          interaction.reply({
            content: 'U hebt hier niet de geschikte permissies voor.',
            ephemeral: true,
          });
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    if (commandObject.botPermissions?.length) {
      for (const permission of commandObject.botPermissions) {
        const bot = interaction.guild.members.me;

        if (!bot.permissions.has(permission)) {
          interaction.reply({
            content: "Ik heb hier geen permissie voor. (geef me 'Administrator' rechten.)",
            ephemeral: true,
          });
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    await commandObject.callback(client, interaction);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`[FOXILITY] There was an error running this command: ${error}`);
  }
};
```

So I wachted some tutorials to make my code but in the tutorials my commands were for a specific guild not global. So I looked at the docs and changed some stuff and it doesn't work.. pls help!

Comment: Does the bot have the necessary permissions?

Comment: It is safe to assume the command execution function is not being called. You should debug each individual conditional present in the code that executes before deciding to call the command, to see which one is failing and / or erroring.

Comment: So what should I do? Pls be more specific I am very new..